# Existence of a solution of a limit of Fixed point equations

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

I am considering a setting where I am given an iid sample of symmetric positive matrices $\{S_i\}$, $i=1,\dots, n$, of a matrix valued random variable $S$ with distribution $F$. The support of $F$ is the set of positive definite matrices.

I am interested in what happens with the following fixed point equation (and its solution) as $n$ goes to infinity
$$
S_{0,n}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(S_{0,n}^{1/2} S_i S_{0,n}^{1/2})^{1/2},
$$
where $S_{0,n}$ is the solution of the fixed point equation. 
I know that, for $n$ fixed, there exists a unique solution. This is proven in [Agueh, Carlier - Barycenters in Wasserstein space](https://www.math.uvic.ca/~agueh/Agueh_Carlier_SIAM2011.pdf) Proof of Theorem 6.1, Step 1 (existence), Step 3 (Uniqueness).

I thought at first, that I could apply the Law of Large Numbers to the random variable $Y_{i,n} := (S_{0,n}^{1/2} S S_{0,n}^{1/2})^{1/2}$. But since $Y_{i,n}$ also depends on $n$ it seems that this is not possible.

Intuitively, I am expecting the sequence of solutions $(S_{0,n})$ to converge to $S_{0,*}$, where $S_{0,*}$ is the solution of the fixed point equation
$$
S_{0,*}= \int  (S_{0,*}^{1/2} S S_{0,*}^{1/2})^{1/2} dP
$$

The context of the problem is Wasserstein barycenters. The Wasserstein barycenter of a set of $n$ Gaussian probability measures $\mu_i \stackrel{def}{=}\mathcal{N}(0, S_i)$ is the measure $\overline{\mu}_n \stackrel{def}{=}\mathcal{N}(0, S_{0,n})$ (Theorem 6.1 in above paper).

I am working on an extension of this to a probabilistic setting where the measures $\mu_i =\mathcal{N}(0, S_i)$ are themselves random obejcts. I assume that they follow a probability distribution $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{N}$ that is induced by a distribution on the space of covariance matrices. I would like to recover the form of the population barycenter of $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{N}$.

I know that, if the sequence $(\overline{\mu}_n)_{n \geq 1}$ weakly converges to a measure $\overline{\mu}$, then $\overline{\mu}$ is a barycenter of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal{N}}$.

Using the continuity of characteristic functions, I obtain

$$
\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\overline{\mu}_n}(t)= \exp(- \frac{1}{2} t^T \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_{0,n} t)
$$ 
Hence, if I can show, that the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_{0,n}$ exists, and, even better, that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_{0,n} = S_{0,*}$, then the sequence $(\overline{\mu}_{n})_{n \geq 1}$ weakly converges and the limit has the characteristic function $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\overline{\mu}_n}(t)$.

Comment: Why is LLN  not enough?  A limit, if it exists,  is always unique.  But you should maybe specify that in this case the limit is taken pointwise a.s..

Comment: I edited my post so as to make clear that the solutions $S_0$ depend on $n$. Mh, well I know that the the limit $lim \frac{1}{n} Y_i$ exists and is uniquely $E[Y]$. Is that what you meant? I also know that for each $n$ I have a unique solution $S_{0,n}$. But don't I need to provide an argument why there also exists a solution of the integral fixed point equation? Or that the limit $lim S_{0,n}$ exists? Thanks

Comment: Ok, sorry for not answering anymore, but I wasn't connected to the internet for some time. Maybe I understand your question. First of all, how do you know that your fixed point equations has got a solution? Second, with your new notation Y_i depends also on n, so you can't apply LLN directly (you should apply your notation everywhere). If I get it right you have the following problem: 1) does $S_{0,n}$ converge somewhere? 2) Does it solve a "Limit fixed point equation"? I don't see a solution easily. But where does the problem come from? Maybe context can help.

Comment: Hey. Thanks very much for coming back to me. Questions 1) and 2) in your comment are exactly what I am trying to solve. I added a section on the context, which is Wasserstein barycenters in the post.

Comment: Sorry for not answering anymore. The problem now is definitely structured better.  Nonetheless I wouldn't know a solution.  In the onedimensional case you can show the claim through writing down the solution and applying the LLN. Maybe the general case can follow from some form or property of the solution.  If I find some time I will try to look through the article! :)